# What files and folders should I have in Laravel if Vue and Vuetify is installed?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

That may sound like an odd question so let me explain why I ask it. I am just learning Laravel, Vue and Vuetify but I haven't found a coherent set of instructions that actually works for installing them except for [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaI9tV8GQFk) Based on the verification steps at the end, it appears that this procedure correctly installs Vue and Vuetify in Laravel.

Unfortunately, I can't find any course on learning Vuetify in Laravel, although [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uZYKcKHgU0&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g0MQZfHwKcuB0Yswgb3gA5&index=1) seems pretty clear for a non-Laravel environment. Unfortunately, the playlist's installation instructions seem to result in a very different structure for the project which bears almost no resemblance to what I see in Laravel. And that is confusing me when it comes to actually writing code.

For instance, at the start of the [third video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGC48C2beoA&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9g0MQZfHwKcuB0Yswgb3gA5&index=3), the narrator starts to go through the first Vuetify code that he is going to teach and the files shown in his IDE are very different than what I have in Laravel. While I do have a node_modules and public folder, as he does, I've also got a bunch of other folders, like app, bootstrap, config, database, resources, storage, route, and vendor but I do *not* have a src folder (nor most of its subfolders, aside from views). I am also lacking an App.vue file, the one he is editing at the start of that video.

I have no idea how to proceed after many hours of searching for videos and tutorials. I am afraid that I am missing a bunch of critical files that I will need but I can't think of any way to determine what those files are nor do I know where to find them.

I am keen to proceed with learning Vuetify but I won't make any progress until I can be certain that I have all the files and folders I need to proceed.

Comment: _"I haven't found a coherent set of instructions"_ ~ https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says specifically that questions asking us to recommend or find off-site resources (which clearly would include *some (free) courses or tutorials*) are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Vue is the most unopinionated framework you have come across. It doesn't require ***any*** folder structure (`node_modules` is imposed by node.js, not by Vue).
So, whatever you think works best for your current project is what you should go for.

---

Obviously, having this type of freedom can be confusing and counter-productive, especially for those who don't know what they want or don't have much experience. Those often need to be told by more experienced others: "*try this thing, it's been tested, works pretty well*".

If you're looking for that type of opinionated advice/structure, give Nuxt a try. Nuxt was developed by people using Vue on a daily basis who, at some point, realized having a similar structure across projects might be beneficial and would allow for even faster prototyping.

---

If all you need is to be certain you're not missing anything crucial, you're not.

All you need to run Vue (and everything that's associated with it, including Vuetify) is one element's id in your page and the vue script loaded, at which point running

```
new Vue({ el: '#host'})
```

will create a Vue instance and use the element with `id="host"` as template.